# Can't open any contacts in Gmail, merge and delete still work though

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

When I load the contacts list in Gmail, I can view the list of contacts but cannot open any. Merge and delete appears to work, I can also access them on my Android device but not via the Gmail UI.

Each time I try to load a contact I get the error

> There was an error loading the contact.

How do I resolve this?  I'm trying to avoid deleting everyone and re-importing them.

I have tried on several computers (Windows 7 and XP) with various browsers (Chrome,  IE8 and IE9).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like it might be a temporary issue on Google's side, not your browser. How long has it happened? If it is recent, I would wait 20 min, an hour, several hours and try again.

If this has been happening for a long time, there may be something wrong with your Gmail account specifically, and I would encourage you to send a bug report to Google directly.

---

Another suggestion to try:
There is an old version of the contacts manager at http://mail.google.com/mail/#cm1

Comment: This has been going on for over a month.  I will send a bug report.  In the mean time thanks for your alternative link

Comment: Does the alt link work for you? Are you able to access individual contacts there?

Comment: The alternative link works fine and I can edit contacts perfectly.  I have sent a report to google

Comment: Great! I can't imagine what it must have been like to not have access to the contacts.